# Am I using " ; " Correctly?

Tags: grammar, semicolons

I really want to know if I'm using semi-colon properly.
"It's nice to know; You're only a call away"

It would just be nice to know.

*I'm in no way, shape or form English. I'm Danish and our grammer is way differnt from the English. I really don't care if you answer it or not.*

Comment: No. It should be "It's nice to know you're only a call away." You also shouldn't use an apostrophe in "want".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know it can be used when u r stating something and u wanna explain it or give some information or examples about it "working out make u healthier;  doing exercises at morning helps your muscles to get stretched, hence, that strengthens them."

Comment: Please write in English. The only English single-letter words are *a* and *I* (capital I) and very occasionally a capital O.